How do i get my SPL token verified on Phantom wallet ? Ive got it listed on Raydium
Need advice on how to get my SPL Token verified

A developer needs to submit your token and follow a few other steps on GitHub
You can find the instructions here
https://github.com/jup-ag/token-list
